# disable userinteraction for single tap on uitextview

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, user-interaction

I've got a UITextView in a tableViewCell

The problem is that when I single tap on the textView it doesn't perform the didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

But I can't set userInteraction = NO because I want to be able to select the text on a long press event

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can so that however if what you want is a way to copy content (text) of a cell how about using the UITableViewDelegate to use the official controls... (like in contacts app where you hold the cell)...

You can achieve it by implementing these methods:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 1) { //eg, we want to copy or paste row 1 on each section
        return YES;
    }
    return NO; //for anything else return no
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender {

    if (action == @selector(copy:)) { //we want to be able to copy

        if... //check for the right indexPath
            return YES;

    }

    return NO; //return no for everything else

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView performAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withSender:(id)sender {

    if (action == @selector(copy:)) {

         //run the code to copy what you want here for indexPath

    }

}
```

Just wrote that from memory so @selector(copy:) might be @selector(copy) (no :) but try it out... You can also add addtional tasks like paste ect but I'll let you figure that out.

Good luck

Comment: Gracias! I did not know about those delegate methods, that's a lot cleaner